# Conditional independance between $A|B$ and $C$ if $B \sim f(C)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $A, B, C$ be 3 random variables such that $A$ and $B$ are not independent, $B \sim f(C)$ (i.e. $C$ is a parameter of the distribution of $B$). Can we say that $A | B$ and $C$ are independent? Intuitively I think it is true: $A$ depends on $C$ only through $B$. However I have no idea how to prove this.

For example, if I have finite vectors $(B_i)_{i \in I}$ and $(C_i)_{i \in I}$ such that $A = \sum_{i \in I}B_i$ where each $B_i$ is let's say a Poisson of parameter $C_i$ (which is itself a Gamma). I know that for every $i \in I$: $A$ and $B_i$ are not independent. ALso $A$ and $C_i$ are not independent. But for a given $i \in I$, are $A | B_i$ and $C_i$ independent?

Comment: Have you tried the basic test of checking if probability of intersection is the product of the two probabilities ? Do you have more specific assumptions to clarify your problem ?

Comment: I'll put an example in the main text, though the question is in the general case

Comment: Ok. Have you tried your example with I reduce to two elements ? I think calculating the conditional laws would be feasible (maybe with a simpler law than a Gamma, though)